# Calculating marginal effects using mlogit in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, mlogit, marginal-effects

I have asked this question on Cross Validated, but think I might not get help as this is more of a programming question rather then theory/interpretation of the statistics.

I am trying to use the `mlogit` package in R and have been following the vignette trying to figure out how to get the marginal effects for my data. The example provided uses continuous variables, but I am wondering how to do this with categorical explanatory variables.

I have a value of risk which is continuous as a covariate, but I also have age, class, and gender as covariates. I want to see the marginal effects of "females" only or of "Young - females" in regard to risk. How would I do this?

The help documents say:

```
z <- with(Fish, data.frame(price = tapply(price, index(m)$alt, mean),
                               catch = tapply(catch, index(m)$alt, mean),
                           income = mean(income)))
# compute the marginal effects (the second one is an elasticity
effects(m, covariate = "income", data = z)
effects(m, covariate = "price", type = "rr", data = z)
effects(m, covariate = "catch", type = "ar", data = z)
```

I'm not sure how to manipulate the `z` data frame to get the mean risk for females or young females to then be able to calculate the marginal effects. Would I do them all separately? Do I somehow divide the data frame by age class (say I have just 2 age classes: young and old) so that I have 1 data frame for the young, and a separate new data frame for old, then calculate mean risk?

What I am hoping to get from my own data is to be able to interpret the magnitude of the likelihood in producing my categories of offspring. As an example, what I want to say is that if there is a 1 unit increase in risk, it is 10% more likely for older females to produce 2 offspring. As there is a 1 unit increase in risk, younger females are 15% more likely to produce 2 offspring.

I am not sure how to calculate the marginal effects by hand, and therefore am confused as to how to get a package to do it for me.  Ive also been trying in the `nnet` library or the `VGAM`, but neither of these seem to give a great deal of help either.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it [is already posted on CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108826/how-to-calculate-marginal-effects-for-categorical-covariates-using-mlogit-in-r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of got an answer - not sure if its the best, but it worked.  My covariate that I was interested in just so happened to be 2 classes - which means I could turn the covariate into a binary 0,1 numeric response.  Therefore, when I rerun the code, I could then calculate the mean for this "categorical" variable.

However, I think that I am missing the point with this marginal effect and am likely using it or trying to interpret it incorrectly.